# dompdf laravel 5.5 error while install composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, laravel

I encountered an error when install composer require barryvdh / laravel-dompdf in laravel 5.5. why?

after install composer i got this error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework v5.5.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.5.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- Installation request for laravel/framework == 5.5.28.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.28].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Please help me, i dont know why getting error like this

Comment: PHP mb-string is required

Comment: It's odd that you installed Laravel (which requires mb-string) and only got this error when trying to install laravel-dompdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `mb-string` package

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

Or for PHP 7  you can do,

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd php-xml php7.0-mbstring
```

Comment: This would work on systems with `apt` (like e.g. Ubuntu) but other Linux distributions has equivalent package managers.

Comment: @SayyidMahdy delete composer.lock and try again

Answer (score 0):

your composer.json is wrong for the php-requirement.

should be e.g. `"php": ">=7.0.0",`

Comment: No, this is not a reason. Because I have faced the same problem today, still my PHP same as you mentioned.